# ElasticBeanstalk nodejs.log can't find module 'hogan.js'

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a simple node.js app that is using `"hogan": "^1.0.2"` (from `packages.json` under `"dependencies"`).

It has been failing to deploy, and looking in the logs, I am seeing (multiple times):

`Error: Cannot find module 'hogan.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:12:17)`

I'm fairly new to node.js on EB, and have just been following http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express.html with a pre-existing Express app.

Assuming EB runs `npm install` for me (is that a safe assumption?), what might the issue be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was using `"hogan": "^1.0.2"` instead of `"hogan.js": "^3.0.2"`, which worked locally but not on EB.

[hogan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hogan) is just an unofficial alias someone made to [hogan.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/hogan.js).

I do not get hogan.js errors any more after making the switch.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I also had an issue similar to this and determined that it was due to file case issues.  In the node EB container, the OS is case-sensitive, and because I was ignoring file case changes in git, it didn't update the file casing in the repository.

You should run `git config core.ignorecase false` if this is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might also change `"hogan": "^3.0.2"` to `"hogan": "*"` because EB does run `npm install` for you. If EB can't find the specific version with "^", it might not install the package as you did locally. Also you might check your file structure before you do `eb create` or `eb deploy`. You might include something unnecessary if you are using the command line. I suggest that you create an `application.zip` file with files you need, such as `package.json`, `app.js` and `index.html` and upload it through GUI. Don't ever pack up `node_modules` in your `.zip` file, that's troublesome.